# Sublimetext goes to the last edited line

Tags: json, node.js, macos

i wanna go to the last line that i edited when i open the app.
I sucessfully to set up the app to open the last open file but it always begin from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll) plugin do the job for you (and other interesting features). The
[description](https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll#description) have the installation instructions.